# Call a subset of a vector in Rcpp (not replacing elements)

Tags: r, subset, rcpp

I'd like to make a function that returns a subset of a vector. In R, it is

```
x <- 1:3 
x[2:3] # return 2nd, 3rd elements
```

My Rcpp code is as follows,

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List subset(arma::vec x){
  return List::create(Named("sub_x") = x.elem(seq(1,2)));
}
```

but it give me an error

```
no matching function for call to 'arma::Col<double>::elem(Rcpp::Range)'
```

I've seen many posts talking about replacing elements in a vector using `.elem`, but it is hard to find something fit to my question, as far as I know of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of comments:

1. You supply a vector. You want a vector. You wrote a function returning a `List`. Hm.
2. The compiler tells you it does know how to stick `Rcpp::Range` into an Armadillo type. That is a good hint.
3. Armadillo has this documented [under element access](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access) and [submatrix view](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat).

So just write

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec mysubset(arma::colvec x) {
  return x.rows(1,2);
}
```

and you're done as seen here:

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/tmp/so51138571.cpp")

R> x <- 1:3

R> mysubset(x)
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]    3
R>
```

This is likely also a duplicate of existing indexing question.

Comment: Thanks, Dirk. For 1, I actually include this code in my main function, so I just let it return a `List`, but thanks for pointing it out.